# difference between d3.event.x and d3.event.pageX

Tags: d3.js

I am using mouse event to capture the area selected.

```
  displayGraph(d3.event);

  function displayGraph(event){
  var x=event.x;
  var y=event.y;
  //var x = event.pageX;
 .........................
  rect.x = x;
  rect.y = y;
....................
}
```

In Firefox, event.x is returning undefined. However it works fine in chrome. When i replace event.x with event.pageX and y with event.pageY it works in both browsers.

What is the difference between event.x and event.pageX. why is it showing as undefined in firefox. Is it not supported in firefox.

Comment: `pageX` and `pageY` are the event's native properties, which are browser-dependent (as you've discovered).

Comment: thanks lars, could you please explain little bit in detail what is meant by native properties and how it is browser dependent.

Comment: These properties depend on the implementation of the rendering engine. In theory, they're specified in a W3C standard, but in practice the implementations don't necessarily conform to that standard.